# Does 'All countable unions' include 'all finite unions'?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, terminology

One of the requirements of a sigma-algebra is that all countable unions are in the algebra i.e. if $A_n\in B$ for $n=0,1,2,...$ ($B$ been our algebra and $A_n\subset U$) then we require:
$$ \bigcup\limits^\infty_{n=1} A_n\in B$$
my question is whether this includes all finite unions i.e. do we also require:
$$A_1 \cup A_4\in B$$
etc?

Comment: Yes by considering empty sets.

Comment: Yes, because there is no requirement that the $A_n$ are distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to see this, view $$A_1 \cup A_4=A_1 \cup A_4 \cup A_1 \cup A_1 \cup \ldots$$

Comment: Better to take $A_1\cup A_4\cup A_1\cup A_1\cup\dots$ since this really has nothing to do with $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can take $A_{2} = A_{3} = A_{4} \cdots$, etc.